# JavaFX 2.0 - how can i embed the application that i build into the web browser now?

Tags: firefox, google-chrome, netbeans, javafx, javafx-2

I have JavaFX application running with my NetBeans IDE. Now how do i deploy it to a browser, so that it works with Chrome, Firefox, Opera, Midori.
(Internet-Explorer not necessary but optional)

[image]

Follow up:

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

run `Clean and Build` and check you `dist` folder.

Comment: Please see my edit. I tried that but i am always getting that right screen msg.

Comment: Unfortunately Browser and WebStart modes require `JavaFX Runtime` which is currently available only on Windows.

Comment: also only supported browsers (for now) are Chrome, Firefox and IE.

Comment: I understand thanks a lot. Please see my edit above. Chrome/Firefox doing same.

Comment: please, see my first comment. There is no Runtime and browser support for Linux yet.